# vim insert output from command mode and increase by one

Tags: regex, vim, command, mode

I would like to make a map to automatically insert the number of matches of some regular expression.  In my vimrc i mapped

```
map <C-A> :%s/^\[^\d*\]//gn<CR>
```

to find the number of footnotes in a document. I want to expand this map such that it inserts the number of matches+1 at the current curser position. So if there were 3 matches, it should insert 4.

Comment: Give example and what is your expected output.

Comment: Have a look at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output as I haven't had time to play with this yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does what you want:

```
function! FootNotes()
    redir => number_of_matches
    silent %s/^\[^\d*\]//gn
    redir END
    return split(number_of_matches)[0] + 1
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <key> FootNotes()
```

Relevant documentation:

```
:help :redir
:help split()
:help <expr>
```